# Is there a way to automatically add rows into a google spreadsheet (using a macro or function)

Tags: database, google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula

I have a google spreadsheet that imports data from various other spreadsheets using the '[import range](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)' function. How the import range function works, is that you specify a range that you want to import from the original spreadsheet. This does not add rows to the spreadsheet, but just pastes data. If there is something in the cell it wants to paste information, an error will appear.

The spreadsheets I manage are constantly changing in size, so I have to manually adjust the range I want to import, and also add/remove more rows to accommodate for the increased/decreased number of rows that want to be copied over.

Here is what my spreadsheet is looking like. The letter 'a' represents a word input, and the number '1' represents a numeric input.
[What my spreadsheet looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kajir.png)

Is there a function or way to use a macro to automatically add the required number of rows to accommodate the frequently updating data?

I thought about potentially using some other function to determine the number of rows in the source spreadsheets, by using counta or the row functions. And then using those values to somehow add/remove enough rows to accommodate the importrange function. But, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.